# Раздумывать о или над?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее сказать: "раздумывать о чем-то" или "раздумывать над чем-то"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно и о чем-то, можно и над чем-то. В словаре сочетаемости: думать о поездке, о предложении. о встрече, о работе, о случившемся, о происшествии, о последствиях, о счастье, о смерти...

Думать над задачей, над примером, над проблемой, над вопросом, над решением...
т.е. *думать над чем-то* предполагает процесс более деятельный что-ли, активный, ищущий решения.